# Json parser to RecyclerView in Android?

Tags: android, json, android-recyclerview

my json:

```
    {
      "info": [
       {
        "key": "headache",
        "value": false
       },
       {
        "key": "fatigue",
        "value": false
       },
       {
        "key": "soreMusclesJoints",
        "value": false
       },
       {
        "key": "soreThroat",
        "value": false
       }
   ]
}
```

I am try to parser:

```
  List<Test1.InfoBean> infoBeanList = new ArrayList<>();
  
  JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(myJson1.toString());
  JSONArray array = jsonObject.getJSONArray("info");
  for(int i=0; i < array.length(); i++){
    JSONObject object = array.getJSONObject(i);
    String key = object.getString("key");
    boolean value = (boolean) object.get("value");
    infoBeanList.add(new Test1.InfoBean());
  }
```

Test1.java

```
  private List<InfoBean> info;
  public Test1(List<InfoBean> info){this.info = info;}
```

I know I am not pass "key" and "value" to adapter, which part is wrong?

please help me , thansk

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Test1.InfoBean class

```java
public class InfoBean{
    private String key;
    private boolean value;
    
    public InfoBean(String key, boolean value) {
        this.key = key;
        this.value = value;
    }
}
```

Main block code

```java
List<Test1.InfoBean> infoBeanList = new ArrayList<>();
  
JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(myJson1.toString());
JSONArray array = jsonObject.getJSONArray("info");
for(int i=0; i < array.length(); i++){
  JSONObject object = array.getJSONObject(i);
  String key = object.getString("key");
  boolean value = object.getBoolean("value");
  -> infoBeanList.add(new Test1.InfoBean(key, value)); <-
}
```